# künstlich / künstlerisch

Tags: etymology

I'm searching for the etymological origin of those words. There is this page on the internet : https://www.expath.de/how-to-say-artsy-and-artificial-in-german/.

But I can't find something about why are those two words so similar in the way they are written, even thought they totally don't mean the same thing. Is its origin a pun ? that someone wanted to do sarcasm about art and instead of saying künstlerisch, said künstlich ?

Comment: _künstlerisch_ => artistic / _künstlich_ => artificial HTH.

Comment: well that's not my question actually... I want to understand why those words seems so similar

Comment: I know. I only tried to give you a hint.

Comment: okay thanks :) but I don't have any idea alone

Comment: What's your native language? French?

Comment: Two more hints (german) [künstlich](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kuenstlich), [künstlerisch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kuenstlerisch)

Comment: *Künstlich* and *künstlerisch* are similar for exactly the same reason why *artificial* and *artistic* are similar.

Comment: *that someone wanted to do sarcasm about art and instead of saying künstlerisch, said künstlich?* You could do that but the usual way of being sarcastic is calling it **Wulst** from *wollen* instead of *Kunst* from *können.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, both *[Kunst](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kunst)*, *[künstlich](https://www.dwds.de/wb/k%C3%BCnstlich)*, *künstlerisch* share their etymology from *Kunst* that was already present in Old High German in the meaning of **knowledge** (*Kenntnis*) and **skill** (*Können*).

It was until in the 18th Century when *künstlich* was indeed used in the meaning of being artfully made or from a technical high level:

> Der Apfel war aber so **künstlich** gemacht, daß der rote Backen allein vergiftet war.<sup>Schneewittchen</sup>

Only later there was a shift in meaning for something that was unnatural, and to an exaggerated extend man made. Then – like in English – the meaning of *künstlich* became *artificial* and most of the original meanings got lost.

This was not the fate of *künstlerisch* (**artistic**), an adjective that only came up much later in the 18th Century for something that was created by an artist. Similarly the adjective *[kunstvoll](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kunstvoll)* (**artful**) maintained its connection to art until today and it now replaces *künstlich* in its pristine meaning.